# hide mobilefirst 7 server information in response header

Tags: http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, websphere-liberty

We have a requirement to hide the mobilefirst 8 server information in response header. And mobilefirst server is installed on Liberty profile. How to close this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about the server level that is part of the response JSON? Why do you wish to hide it?

Comment: Hi Vivin, we have a set up like IHS ----> MobileFirst. request comes from IBM HTTP Server to MobileFirst server. While testing the application with some wrong JSON data/URLs in the response the server version is displating with 403 forbidden error and the message is APPLICATION DOES NOT EXIST appended with sever version.

Comment: Hi Vivin, It's vendor requirement to hide the server version details in response for security reasons.

Comment: Will you please post the exact message so that we can see if the information is coming from Liberty of MobileFirst?  Meaning, what is the 'server version' text?

Comment: And please update the question itself with all the details, not just added as comments.